# QGIS system architecture

Tags: qgis

I'd like to develop a simple spatial system with database for plotting and managing geographic features.I thought I should install on an ubuntu server:

1. qgis server
2. postgreSQL
3. postGIS

and write python qt modules to access the data from android devices and desktop PCs.

Could helpful people let me know if I'm on the right track?
Thanks
Mini

Comment: Why do you want to write new code? There is QGIS for desktop and Android. Also, if you are more specific about your requirements, you'll get better answers.

Comment: It seems that you are mixing things. You want a simple system for plotting and managing features or you want a  server for remote access from Android devices and PCs?